# Xamarin forms transparency and custom control

Tags: wpf, xamarin

I'm developing a cross-platform game board (WPF and Android).
I have a grid inside a scrollView layout and in each cell i inflate this
cell custom control

```
<ContentView.Content>
 <Frame x:Name ="fr" BorderColor="Black" Padding="0">
  <Grid HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" >
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
         </Grid.RowDefinitions>
           <Label Grid.Row="0" x:Name="txt"/>
           <Image Grid.Row="0" x:Name="img"/>
         </Grid>
  </Frame>
</ContentView.Content>
```

The problem is that in Android the control is not transparent as in WPF.

see:

**WPF**

[image: WPF]

**Android**

[image: Android]

Answer (score 1):

Try using `Transparent` background color for the `Frame`:

```
<ContentView.Content>
 <Frame x:Name ="fr" BackgroundColor="Transparent" BorderColor="Black" Padding="0">
  <Grid HorizontalOptions="FillAndExpand" >
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
      <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
         </Grid.RowDefinitions>
           <Label Grid.Row="0" x:Name="txt"/>
           <Image Grid.Row="0" x:Name="img"/>
         </Grid>
  </Frame>
</ContentView.Content>
```